# inputtextarea primefaces break line

Tags: primefaces, textarea

I having a problem with this component.

The problem is when i input a long text without any blank space or line break it takes the text without any breaks.

I want the component addding a `<br/>` element to solve this problem:

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_88191981.jpg 
http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_88192002.jpg

Comment: Have you tried to define a fixed width for the outputLabel?

Comment: Hello, there is my problem when I try to set max width for the label nothing happends. Its posted the using code below:

Comment: Remove the `escape=false`, it prevent the line-break

Comment: I remove it but it dosnt help. escape=false interprate html code, that its ok for me,but i need to include the <br> element:

Some images with escape = false:

Comment: It seems to be the same problem than when i using primefaces editor; if I dont input any blank space or line-break it adds infinite horizontal scroll, then if i add blank space and continue writing it jumps automatic to next line. It can be evidenced ir primefaces demo:

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf

When the scroll appears if you press space bar cursor jumps to next line...

¿Any idea why its working so weird?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finaly the problem was solved including a div container with wrap-word property:

```
    <h:column>

       <div style="word-wrap: break-word; width:900px;">
         <p:outputLabel value="#{comentario.descripcion}"  escape="false"/>
     </div>
   </h:column>
```